# Why is `if string[0] == '0':` working but also giving an error?

Tags: python, excel, string, openpyxl

I'm **really** new to programing and I'm trying to make my first "project";
the project is pretty taking my bank report excels and summarize them useing openpyxl.

Anyway..I'm trying to work with dates and recive the month in a string of date, and it's kind of working, but it give me some weird error in the output:

```
**Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Avi...Bank/Python App/app.py", line 22, in <module>
    if month[0] == '0':
IndexError: string index out of range**
```

this is all the code:

```
from pathlib import PureWindowsPath
import openpyxl as xl
import datetime as dt

wb_inputs = PureWindowsPath('D:/Avi...Inputs.xlsx')
wb_outputs = PureWindowsPath('D:/Aviv...Outputs.xlsx')

wb_inputs = xl.load_workbook(wb_inputs)
wb_outputs = xl.load_workbook(wb_outputs)

input1_sheet = wb_inputs['Input1']
input2_sheet = wb_inputs['Input2']
input3_sheet = wb_inputs['Input3']
output1_sheet = wb_outputs['Output1 - Summary']
output2_sheet = wb_outputs['Output2 - data']

for row in range(23, input3_sheet.max_row + 1):
    cell = input3_sheet.cell(row, 1)
    price_for_cell = input3_sheet.cell(row, 6)
    date_cell = str(cell.value)
    month = date_cell[5:7]
    if month[0] == '0':
        print(month[1])
    else:
        print(month)
```

Comment: The error message means that `month` is empty.  Excel stores dates as numbers, not strings.

Comment: It indicates that you've reached a row where your `month` comes out as an empty string. You can't read index 0 from an empty string.

Comment: Creating your own counter makes the code harder to read and more likely to make mistakes. Use the openpyxl API to avoid this such as `for row in ws.iter_rows(min_row=24, values_only=True): date = row[0]; price=row[7]` And use Python datetime.strptime function to convert the date for you.

Answer (score 1):

This is runtime error.

The value of variable `month` is dependent on variable `row` indirectly.

Therefore, whenever the value of variable `month` comes out to be an empty string, you cannot access the 0th index of an empty string.

**I would suggest you 2 things:**

1. Check the range for `for` loop to avoid logical errors.
2. Use of exception handling to maintain a normal flow of application.

Comment: hey thank a lot!
I fixed it by telling python to ignor  the None variable:

    if cell.value is None:
        pass

Comment: Kindly accept the answer if it solves your use case